# How get the variable value outside javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a code which is used to send a GET request via javascript. I'm new to javascript and would like to seek your help for the following issue.

Following is my javascript code and is there a way to call **var title** value outside the function. As an example after the line **request.send();** . I would be obliged if you could help me out.

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  
  request.onload = function () {
    console.log(request);
    if (request.status == 200){
      console.log(JSON.parse(request.response));
      var obj = JSON.parse(request.response);
     
      if (obj.id == 1)
      {
        var title = obj.title;
        //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = title;
      }
      
    }else {
      console.log(`error ${request.status} ${request.statusText}`);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Error";
    }
  
  }
  request.send();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = title;
```

Comment: No, you can't. Why don't you just use the line that is commented out? It would work.

Comment: Oh okay. Yes commented line is working. But I need to take the title value after the function.